# How to ensure a gem's executable loads the dependencies from the gemspec?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

In my gem's gemspec, I specify a dependency of another gem (`anothergem`) with an explicit version, say `1.12.2`. If the system already has `anothergem` version `1.12.1`, my gem's executable will `require` the wrong version. So,

**How can I ensure my gem's executable loads the intended version of the gem's dependencies?**

To be clear, the executable (`mygemexec`) should be able to be called from anywhere without the need of `bundle exec`. Example:

```
gem install mygem
mygemexec
```

EDIT: The way I am setting the dependency version in the gemspec is:

```
spec.add_dependency 'anothergem', '1.12.2'
```

Comment: This should happen already. When you call a gem executable Ruby will set it up so that the correct gem versions are used. A possible issue using the correct dependencies if you call the executable in development, but that doesn’t seem to be what you are asking here.

Comment: @matt Yeah the "should happen already" is what I expected, but it certainly is using an older version of the gem already on my system. I'm not sure what you mean by calling the executable in development

Comment: By development I mean if you try to run the executable file directly from the source folder without installing it as a gem – then the dependencies specified in the gem won’t be used. Are you sure you’ve got the versions the right way round in your question – Ruby will use the latest version by default. I think you will need to give more information about your situation in order to find a solution.